# Android Studio autogenerated code

Tags: android, android-studio

I run my application in Android Studio and I have in my Java file autogenerated code.
I get errors related to that code/see below that I cannot explain.
I appreciate your help.

```
// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


error: <identifier> expected ----------------------- When I click this error it points to client =... line above.
Error:(106, 16) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:(111, 13) error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your code inside a method and call it from somewhere (for instance in onCreate). Also make sure that you specify type of variable before defining it.

For instance:

```
private GoogleApiClient.Builder client;
private void METHOD_NAME() {
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

or

```
private void METHOD_NAME() {
    GoogleApiClient.Builder client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually the class declaration is there. File too big to post  
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ......

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Your answer may is right but I had to restructure my whole code and I do not need this line anymore. Basically I gave up on that. Thanks anyways.